# jar -C behavior for multiple files

Tags: java, linux, jar

I'm trying to understand what I find a strange behavior for `jar`.

**TL;DR** `jar -C dir file1 file2 file3` expects `file1` relative to `dir` and all other `file2`, `file3`, ... relative to current directory.

---

I have a directory containing many classes and want to create a jar file with some of them (i.e. not all from a specific directory). I also need to include some resources from another directory and want the paths stored in the jar relative to those directories:

```
$ tree
.
├── classes
│   └── com
│       ├── c2.class
│       └── cc1.class
└── ressources
│   └── res
│       ├── a.png
│       └── b.png
```

I want to have a jar storing these paths:

```
com/cc1.class
com/c2.class
res/a.png
res/b.png
```

I initially thought using `-C` before adding each individual files from the same "group" directory but it's not working:

```
$ jar -cf test.jar -C classes/ com/cc1.class com/c2.class -C resources/ res/a.png res/b.png
com/c2.class : no such file or directory
res/b.png : no such file or directory
```

The error is on the second file only; the first one begin OK...

```
$ jar -cf test.jar -C classes/ com/cc1.class ./classes/com/c2.class -C resources/ res/a.png ./resources/res/b.png
```

Jar was created successfully:

```
$ jar tf test.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
com/cc1.class
com/c2.class
res/a.png
res/b.png
```

The behaviour feels odd: I have to give the *first* file a path *relative to `-C`* and all other files a path *relative to `.`* (or an absolute path also works)?

The `man` says:

> -C DIR Changes the specified directory and includes the **files** specified at the end of the command line.

(note the plural `include the *files*`).

... but `jar --help` says otherwise:

> -C DIR  Change to the specified directory and include the **following file**

(note the singular `include the *following file*`).

Indeed, the `jar --help` is correct and `man` is misleading, but why that behavior?

`jar --version` gives `jar 18.0.2-ea`.

Comment: A jar is literally a zip file with a manifest. Your `jar tf` shows the desired classes were jarred with the desired structure. **What** are you asking? Why the command doesn't work like you thought it should from the documentation? Why are you even using jar manually? You should be using a build tool. And it should do the packaging.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I'm asking why the *first* file should be relative to the directory specified by `-C` when all others should be absolute or relative to current directory (which leads to *"why the inconsistency between `man` and `--help`"*).

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/specs/man/jar.html) isn’t very clear on how multiple `-C` options work, and in fact I see a mistake in that documentation.  It does seem to faintly imply that all files after a -C *dir* should be relative to *dir*.

Comment: @VGR indeed, the documentation is misleading on that point, but that's how I would expect it to work. And tbh I wasn't sure whether multiple `-C` would work, I tried my luck... ;)

Comment: On the other hand, `jar --help` describes the `-C` option with “Change to the specified directory and include the following file”.  The word ‘file’ is singular.  I have might have questioned whether that’s a careful decision or merely a bit of carelessness, but your observation seems to suggest the former.